# Как перебрать многомерный массив JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть две группы блоков "дети" и "родители".
нужно чтобы класс `.acrive` первоначально присвоился к родителю, затем ко всем его детям, затем перешел с следующему родителю и т.д.
Попробовал 2 способа

1 способ:

```js
$(".field-name-field-iconresults").each(function(i, el) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).addClass("active");
      }, 400 + (i * 400));
      $('.field-name-field-iconresults .field-item').each(function(j, chel) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(chel).addClass("active");
        }, 400 + (j * 800));
      })
    });
```

```css
.field-name-field-iconresults .field-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #8BC34A;
}
.field-name-field-iconresults .field-item.active {
  background: #FF9800;
}
.field-name-field-iconresults {
  border: 2px dotted #E91E63;
}
.field-name-field-iconresults.active {
    border: 2px dotted #8BC34A;
    background: #B2EBF2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-content">
  <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
    <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item" property="dc:title">
          <h2>Первый элемент</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-iconresults field-type-image field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">

        </div>
        <div class="field-item">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
    <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item" property="dc:title">
          <h2>Второй элемент</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-iconresults field-type-image field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">

        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
    <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item" property="dc:title">
          <h2>Третий элемент</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-iconresults field-type-image field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even views-row-last">
    <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item" property="dc:title">
          <h2>Последний элемент</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-iconresults field-type-image field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2 способ:

```js
$(".field-name-field-iconresults").each(function(i, el) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  $(el).addClass("active");
  $(el).find('.field-item').each(function(j, chel) {
   setTimeout(function() {
   $(chel).addClass("active");
   }, 400 + (j * 800));
   })
 }, 400 + (i * 400));
});
```

```css
.field-name-field-iconresults .field-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #8BC34A;
}
.field-name-field-iconresults .field-item.active {
  background: #FF9800;
}
.field-name-field-iconresults {
  border: 2px dotted #E91E63;
}
.field-name-field-iconresults.active {
    border: 2px dotted #8BC34A;
    background: #B2EBF2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-content">
  <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
    <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item" property="dc:title">
          <h2>Первый элемент</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-iconresults field-type-image field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">

        </div>
        <div class="field-item">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
    <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item" property="dc:title">
          <h2>Второй элемент</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-iconresults field-type-image field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">

        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
    <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item" property="dc:title">
          <h2>Третий элемент</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-iconresults field-type-image field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even views-row-last">
    <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item" property="dc:title">
          <h2>Последний элемент</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-iconresults field-type-image field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Оба способа не подходят, для поставленной задачи, регулирование временного интервала, считаю не универсальным, так как количество "детей" у "родителей" разное.
Возможно есть способ перебрать как массив, но с ними мне трудно дается подружиться)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

составить очередь(массив) и обходить элементы массива через таймер.

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = [];
  $(".field-name-field-iconresults").each(function(i, el) {
    arr.push(el);
    $(".field-item", el).each(function(i, el) {
      arr.push(el)
    })
  });
  ! function show() {
    var el = arr.shift();
    if (el) {
      $(el).addClass("active");
      window.setTimeout(show, 800)
    }
  }()
});
```

```css
.field-name-field-iconresults .field-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #8BC34A;
}
.field-name-field-iconresults .field-item.active {
  background: #FF9800;
}
.field-name-field-iconresults {
  border: 2px dotted #E91E63;
}
.field-name-field-iconresults.active {
  border: 2px dotted #8BC34A;
  background: #B2EBF2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-content">
  <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
    <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item" property="dc:title">
          <h2>Первый элемент</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-iconresults field-type-image field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">

        </div>
        <div class="field-item">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
    <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item" property="dc:title">
          <h2>Второй элемент</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-iconresults field-type-image field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">

        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
    <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item" property="dc:title">
          <h2>Третий элемент</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-iconresults field-type-image field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even views-row-last">
    <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item" property="dc:title">
          <h2>Последний элемент</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-iconresults field-type-image field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А это это означает?  `! function` никогда раньше не встречался (да и опыта большого нет)